# MSBUILD: Build Package including extra files

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I've been having some serious challenges over the past week trying to implement the solution located at: http://blog.samstephens.co.nz/2010-10-18/msbuild-including-extra-files-multiple-builds/.

It's based off of Sayed's implementation: http://sedodream.com/CommentView,guid,803d77d7-a220-4cee-a803-f6291cd4ba71.aspx (which works perfectly), however I need files from multiple locations and Sayed's solution doesn't account for that scenario.

While in theory Sam's solution provides *exactly* what I need, I can't get it to build (despite cut and pasting his solution and only modifying the paths to reflect my environment).  I've been banging my head against the following error for several days:

```
[15:31:30]: [CopyPipelineFiles] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852, 5): error MSB4018: The "CopyPipelineFiles" task failed unexpectedly.  
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.  
at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path) at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)  
at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CopyPipelineFiles.CopyPipelineFilesToFolder(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] allpipeLineItems, String sourceFolderName, String targetFolderName, ItemMetadataFilter itemMetadataSkipFilter, Boolean fUpdateItemSpec, Boolean deleteItemsMarkAsExcludeTrue, List`1 updatedPipeLineItems, List`1 failedPipeLineItems)  
at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CopyPipelineFiles.Execute()  
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() 
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)    
[15:31:31]: Process exited with code 1  
[15:31:31]: MSBuild output:  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: The "CopyPipelineFiles" task failed unexpectedly. [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path) [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2) [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CopyPipelineFiles.CopyPipelineFilesToFolder(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] allpipeLineItems, String sourceFolderName, String targetFolderName, ItemMetadataFilter itemMetadataSkipFilter, Boolean fUpdateItemSpec, Boolean deleteItemsMarkAsExcludeTrue, List`1 updatedPipeLineItems, List`1 failedPipeLineItems) [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CopyPipelineFiles.Execute() [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult) [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: Done Building Project "<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj" (Package target(s)) -- FAILED.  
[15:31:31]: Done Building Project "C:\buildAgent\work\8aa6ae640d0f858b\main\scripts\MYPROJ.csproj" (BatchCopyPackage target(s)) -- FAILED.  
[15:31:31]: Build FAILED.  
[15:31:31]: "C:\buildAgent\work\8aa6ae640d0f858b\main\scripts\MYPROJ.csproj" (BatchCopyPackage target) (1) ->  
[15:31:31]: "<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj" (Package target) (2) ->  
[15:31:31]: (CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage target) ->  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: The "CopyPipelineFiles" task failed unexpectedly. [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path) [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2) [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CopyPipelineFiles.CopyPipelineFilesToFolder(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] allpipeLineItems, String sourceFolderName, String targetFolderName, ItemMetadataFilter itemMetadataSkipFilter, Boolean fUpdateItemSpec, Boolean deleteItemsMarkAsExcludeTrue, List`1 updatedPipeLineItems, List`1 failedPipeLineItems) [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CopyPipelineFiles.Execute() [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult) [<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj]  
[15:31:31]: 0 Warning(s)  
[15:31:31]: 1 Error(s)  
[15:31:31]: Time Elapsed 00:00:23.00
```

Here's my implementation of Sam's targets:

```
<Target Name="DefineCustomFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <CustomFilesToInclude Include="$(workingDir)\main\img\**\*">
        <Dir>img</Dir>
      </CustomFilesToInclude>
      <CustomFilesToInclude Include="$(workingDir)\main\Service References\**\*">
        <Dir>ServiceReferences</Dir>
      </CustomFilesToInclude>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
  <Message Text="Here is a file list: %(CustomFilesToInclude.Identity)" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="@(CustomFilesToInclude)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>
          %(CustomFilesToInclude.Dir)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)
        </DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I thought it may have something to do with spaces (or the wildcard symbols) so here's what I've tried:

- Examined the log with both "detailed" and "diagnostic" logging levels
- Various incarnations of mixing double quotes and single quotes
- Commenting out the "Service References" node.  (The paths containing imgs have no spaces)
- Pointing to a single file with an absolute path. Therefore eliminating both wildcards and errors due to the path containing spaces.  I thought FOR SURE this would resolve the issue, but it failed with the same error above.

After issue #3 I'm at a complete loss.  It doesn't like *any* files passed to it.

Any insight would be GREATLY appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Here is how my target currently looks and the respective error message:

```
<Target Name="DefineCustomFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <CustomFilesToInclude Include="$(workingDir)\main\img\file.gif">
        <Dir>img</Dir>
      </CustomFilesToInclude>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852, 5): error MSB4018: The "CopyPipelineFiles" task failed unexpectedly.  
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
```

Comment: You can call msbuild with diagnostic logging turned on, and then examine the log around the place where it constructs list of files in the ItemGroup you suspect. This might point you to the problem.

Comment: Hi Seva,

Thank you. I probably should have included in my post that I did examine the log with a diagnostic verbosity. (I have edited the post accordingly). Unfortunately diagnostic logging didn't reveal any clarification other than what the detailed log had already exposed.

Comment: In your log I do see <PATH_TO> as part of your project. If this is not a hand edit I am sure that < and > are not allowed characters for a complete path to a project.

Comment: Yes.  The <PATH_TO> was an intentional hand edit. In the actual file the path is legitimate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found your issue, and I'm afraid it's my fault. The issue is that whitespace is significant within the `DestinationRelativePath` element of `FilesForPackagingFromProject`. I added whitespace in when I did the blog post to make the XML easier to read, without realising that it would cause the code to fail.

So if you try

```
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
  <Message Text="Here is a file list: %(CustomFilesToInclude.Identity)" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="@(CustomFilesToInclude)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>%(CustomFilesToInclude.Dir)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Your problems should hopefully be fixed. I've updated the blog post to remove the offending whitespace.

Note that, as Scott Stafford points out in his comment below, CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn has been renamed to CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Sam, this immediately resolved the issue.  Thank you, Thank you, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!  You are a lifesaver!

Comment: NOTE: in VS2012, the key target is CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn.

Answer (score 3):

This works in Visual Studio 2013 for Web:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="bin\**" Exclude="**/.git*" />
    <Content Include=".\Global.asax" />
    <Content Include=".\umbraco\**" />
    <Content Include=".\usercontrols\**" />
    <Content Include=".\umbraco_client\**" />
    <Content Include=".\App_Code\**" />
    <Content Include=".\App_Plugins\**" />
    <Content Include=".\App_Data\*-*-*-*-*\**" />
    <Content Include=".\App_Data\packages\**" />
    <Content Include=".\App_Data\access.*" />
    <Content Include=".\Views\**" />
    <Content Include=".\App_Browsers\**" />
    <Content Include=".\uSync\**" />
    <Content Include=".\media\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

This specific example is from an Umbraco 4 project.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a problem like this, with a target similar to the suggestion in Saustrup's answer.

In my case, the problem was actually that my target was running too late, so creating the files after the application had been built, packaged, and deployed. This is because I was using `BeforeTargets="Build"` to run my target. I've covered this in a lot more detail in an answer to a more relevant question (which I only found *after* solving the problem) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986147/target-not-running-when-using-beforetargets-build-on-build-server/31424691#31424691).

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild, as you've indicated, does have issues with spaces. Have you tried adding double slashes:

```
"$(workingDir)\\main\\Service References\\**\\*"
```

Comment: Hi Ben,  

Thank you. I had not tried that.  I just tried it and, unfortunately it failed on the same error. Remember, at this point, I refer to an absolute path that I am sure has no spaces.

Comment: Hmmm. Have you checked Alois his comment about the "<PATH_TO>\MYPROJ.csproj" path in the previous answer?