# .NET Core csproj PublishProfileName has a value when building

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild

I'm using the following sample to dynamically produce the `Web.config` file:

https://sebnilsson.com/blog/asp-net-transform-web-config-with-debug-release-on-build/

The change includes this in the .csproj which works in regular .NET:

`<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(PublishProfileName)' == '' And '$(WebPublishProfileFile)' == ''">`

However, when a similar line is used in .NET Core, it doesn't work because `PublishProfileName` is actually 'FileSystem'. What I'd like is a way to detect publish (vs build) to avoid the issue of modifying Web.config twice. Here's the modified part for .NET Core:

```
  <Target Name="TestTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Firing on publish due to PublishProfile being '$(PublishProfileName)'" />
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
  </Target>
```

Does anyone know how to do the same thing in .NET core as was done in .NET to stop double modification of web.config when dynamically produced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'd like is a way to detect publish (vs build) to avoid the issue
>   of modifying Web.config twice.

The easiest way i think is using `Condition="'$(DeployOnBuild)' != 'true'"` in your target.
Then this target will only be executed during build process but not publish process.

```
<Target Name="TestTarget" Condition="'$(DeployOnBuild)' != 'true'" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Firing on publish due to PublishProfile being '$(PublishProfileName)' and " />
    <!--<TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />-->
  </Target>
```

This will make sure when you publishing the project in VS by FileSystem, it will only execute the target `once in build` instead of `twice in build and publish`. I'm not sure why you set the `AfterTargets="Build"`, according to the article you mentioned above, it might be `BeforeTargets="Build"`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try your solution. I have to use AfterTargets="build" instead of BeforeTargets because BeforeTargets doesn't work for me.

This article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986147/target-not-running-when-using-beforetargets-build-on-build-server suggests using BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" but that also didn't work for me. In the end if it's before or after the build it doesn't matter anyways so it's ok.

Comment: @automaton Any update feel free to contact me:) If the DeployOnBuild not works, you can share some details so we can reproduce it.

Comment: So this is definitely working, thank you. However a new problem has arisen. This works on local builds, but on our build server it fails with an error that a dependency needs a binding re-direct. The thing is that binding re-direct is in the web.config file that is dynamically produced. I tried `<Target Name="CreateWebConfig" BeforeTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences"` and `<Copy SourceFiles="Web.Base.config" DestinationFiles="Web.config" />` but it didn't solve it, even when included as Content in the csproj. So now I'm stuck again.

Comment: @automaton Does the build server uses Build Tools Package without VS installed? And the error occurs when building and publish in msbuild.exe from build Tools? Most of the time the results should be the same when building by VS and Build Tools Package, so i assume if some component is missing in your server. Maybe you can open a new thread and share the details about this new issue, and share the original error message there, so that we can research it deeply:)

Comment: After a lot of effort, the problem could be replicated by using msbuild on command line (but not VS). Diagnostic mode indicates AppConfigWithTargetPath is not set when Web.config not present on disk during build (second build works). Solution was to use InitialTargets on Project with 2 targets, 1 which uses AppConfigWithTargetPath if file does not exist, and the other which always produces Web.config. It's a really silly issue and I believe it's a bug in msbuild, but this is as far as I can go debugging. Appreciate the help.